# Eclipse IDE 2019-03 for 32 bit ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, eclipse, 32-bit

Did eclipse stop development of 32-bit eclipse? There is no 32-bit version for eclipse IDE from 2018-12 releases onwards. I have 32-bit ubuntu installed on 64-bit machine.

Can I install latest eclipse IDE 2019-03 on this 32-bit OS? If yes, how can I do that?

Comment: Which 32bit OS?  You didn't say.  Of note, both Xubuntu and Lubuntu dropped x86 ISOs in Dec-2018 (other flavors and main Ubuntu having already dropped x86 for their primary ISOs).   There were few users, and fewer users willing to contribute (esp. test) was a primary listed reason.

Comment: Recent releases of Eclipse are 64 bit only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last 32 bit release of Eclipse was 2018-09. From release 2018-12 onwards only 64 bit releases are available. You can't run the 64 bit release on a 32 bit OS.